# Print Css not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to load my print.css but it  does not seem to be loading. it work Fine in FF and Safari but the problem is only in IE.

I have the regular external css for the page inbetween  the head tags

And when the user click on the print link . it loads the print css .

```
<div class="linkPrint">
<a target="_blank" href="?format=print">Print</a>
</div>


var format = getUrlParam('format');
if (format == 'print') {
    $('head').append('<link href="/theme/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
}
```

But,in IE it load the standard css instead of the print.css.

How do can this be fixed for IE6?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use standard DOM methods like `document.createElement("link")`, etc., and append *that* to the `head`?

Answer (score 7):

You can have the print CSS and your screen CSS both loaded at the same time on the page without them interfering with each other - you need to specify the [`media`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) attribute on the `link` tag:

```
<link href="/theme/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link href="/theme/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

No need to go through the javascript trickery.

As for IE6 - it does support this, as can be seen on the comparison list on [this](http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/print-BrowserSummary.shtml) page.

Comment: Thanks yes that one way. But I cant use that in this case. How can  this work in IE6 using the above javascript, it work fine in FF and Safari and Crome, but fails in IE6

Comment: How come you can't use this, but can use a javascript hack?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<link>` to the other css file when you append the print.css

Answer (score 0):

try with document.write,

```
document.write('<link href="/theme/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```